# Maxima, how to do something like Table in Mathematica

Tags: maxima

Maxima, how to do something like Table in Mathematica?

In Mathematica I can do

```
listA=Table[k,{k,1,100}]
```

How do I do the same thing in maxima?

Answer (score 1):

I think `makelist` is the function you want. E.g. `listA : makelist(i, i, 1, 100)` to make a list `[1, 2, 3, ..., 100]`. You can nest `makelist` to make a nested list. See also `create_list` and `genmatrix`.